# Executing client-side DOM manipulation after static rendering in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I would like to render a Tripetto form in my NextJS static page. Unfortunately, the Tripetto library uses the "window" object, which is undefined with static rendering.

Is there a way to execute client-side Javascript after static rendering in NextJS to avoid this issue?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window` is not defined **server side**. You can import Tripetto by using `next/dynamic` import in this way :

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
const Tripetto = dynamic(()=> import('Tripetto'), {ssr: false})
```

Doing this next will load your lib **client side** and `window` will be defined